# Mobility Radeon HD 5650 and windows 8

Tags: graphics-card, windows-8-preview

I just installed Windows 8 and I am having issues getting my graphics driver updated.  I have a AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5650 - I downloaded the proper file from their site but every time I try to install it, it tells me the driver failed to install.  Final Status: Fail 
Version of Item: 8.972.4.0000  Size: 90 Mbytes

The video card shows up in the device manager with the yellow symbol, when I look at the properties it says that the device cant start - I am assuming because it has no drivers.  Interestingly, if I start the computer in safe mode the yellow symbol goes away but I can't run the driver install file in safe mode.  I don't know what else to try.

Computer is a Acer Aspire 8943g laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "proper file from their site"?

If you mean that, you downloaded the driver from the AMD site, it very probably will not work with your laptop. Mobile GPUs require special drivers, which mostly delivered by the manufacturer (in this case, Acer).

[Go to this support site](https://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?modelId=2132) and download the correct driver for your model.

Comment: The only ones available on their site are for windows 7 - besides that the package notes for the updated release from the AMD site does specifically state that the driver install file works for AMD Mobility Radeon™ HD 5000 Series as well.

Comment: Well, *should* work and *works* are two separate things in the world of mobile GPU drivers. I know, Samsung and Acer build pretty vanilla GPUs, therefore it should work, but your laptop is not guaranteed to support Windows 8, so, again, I am not so sure.

Comment: heh good point.